# PermissionError [Errno 13] Permission denied python3 django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Recién estoy aprendiendo **django** y todo me funciona bien hasta que intento abrir mi `html` desde una carpeta, introduje la ruta y todo correctamente, pero al abrir la página me da  **PermissionError   [Errno 13] Permission denied.** [image: me sale este error al final de la pagina]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posiblemente la carpeta `templates` o anteriores, tienen permisos que limitan ciertas acciones. Por otra parte, la función `open()` no esta abriendo ningún archivo o fichero, lo cual dará error.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no tienes permisos de lectura en esa carpeta o puede que la ruta este mal tipeada, fuera de esto es una muy mala práctica tratar de acceder con la ruta completa a los TEMPLATES,  la manera correcta es acceder usando *'app/template.html'*.

Puedes solucionar tu problema configurando en tu archivo settings la carpeta/s donde tendrás tus templates usando la configuración correspondiente, ej:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
)
```

Por defecto ya debes tenerlo configurado, entonces basta con que renderizas utilizando bien la función **render** un shortcut que te permite pasar el contexto y el template de esta forma:

from django.shortcuts import render

```
def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {
        'foo': 'bar',
    })
```

O la manera tradicional:

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

```
def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    t = loader.get_template('myapp/index.html')
    c = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c, request), content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

Puedes ver más información en la [documentación oficial de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#example)